# How do I change an Iframe from a text form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, textbox

I am trying to have an iframe in which you can change the url of it with a text box.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
 URL: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="test.com"> <input type="submit" value="Visit">
</form>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: you have to come here at least with something, an idea, a piece of code, show us you have tried something

Comment: Your form action is "/action_page.php" but you don't seem to have tagged PHP, we need more details about how you want that to be as mentioned by Pierre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function onClick() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe');
  const input = document.querySelector('#input');
  
  iframe.src = input.value;
}
```

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button onclick="onClick()">click</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```